# A question of primal-dual formulation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose we have the primal problem:

$\mathop{\min}\limits_{x\in X} F(Kx)+G(x)$,

where $F,K,G$ are linear operators. And I want to ask how is the primal-dual formulation work to get the saddle-point problem form:

$\mathop{\min}\limits_{x\in X}\mathop{\max}\limits_{y\in Y} \langle Kx,y\rangle +G(x)-F^{*}(y)$,

where $X,Y$ are two finite-dimensional spaces, and $F^{*}$ is the conjugate function of $F$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Can you be more specific in your question. This would require one to provide a very long answer and explain all concepts involved in the derivation of the dual problem, including strong duality.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I am reading the article A first-order primal dual algorithm for convex problems with applications to imaging by Antonin Chambolle, and my question is how to get the formula (2) from a primal problem (formula (3) and (4)); I think I have kow all the related concept like duality, conjugate function etc., but I just do not know how to get this sadlle-point form, please help me!

Comment: Would you like to show what you have tried? Did you try to write down $F^*$ using the definition and use the fact that $F$ is lsc, therefore, $F=F^{**}$?

Comment: I can only get a inequality by the definition of conjugate function: $\mathop{\min}\limits_{x\in X} F(Kx)+G(x)\geq\mathop{\min}\limits_{x\in X}\mathop{\max}\limits_{y\in Y}G(x)+<Kx,y>-F^{*}(y)$, which I guess is wrong. And I do not know the property of $F=F^{**}$, could your recommand me a book with properties of lsc and primal-dual formulation to refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\<}{\left\langle}\newcommand{\>}{\right\rangle}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\Rbar}{\overline{\R}}$Recall that for a convex function $F:\R^n\to\Rbar$, its convex conjugate, $F^*:\R^n\to\Rbar$, is defined as

$$
F^*(y) = \sup_{x} \<x, y\> - F(x).
$$

The conjugate of the conjugate, $F^{**}:\R^n\to\Rbar$ is

$$
F^*(x) = \sup_{y} \<x, y\> - F^*(y).
$$

By the Fenchel-Moreau Theorem, if $F$ is convex then $F$ is lsc and convex if and only in $F=F^{**}$.

You can find this in several books such as (i) Theorem 12.2 in R.T. Rockafellar, "Convex Analysis," Princeton University Press, 1970, (ii) Theorem 13.32 in H.H. Bauschke and P.L. Combettes, "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces," Springer, 2011.

As a result, assuming that $F$ is proper and lsc,

$$
\operatorname*{Minimize}_{x} F(Kx) + G(x),
$$

is equivalent to

$$
\operatorname*{Minimize}_{x} F^{**}(Kx) + G(x),
$$

which is equivalent to

$$
\operatorname*{Minimize}_{x} \sup_{y} \<Kx, y\> - F^*(y) + G(x).
$$

You need some additional assumptions to turn $\sup$ into a $\max$. In particular, you need to assume that $F^*$ is level-bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!